# What are the functions that look like table in Lua?

Tags: c++, function, lua, lua-table

I'm a beginner in Lua and I just found out some functions look like table (e.g. `function love.update(dt)`) in Lua.

I wonder how these functions work. For example, does `update` function belong to table `love`? If so, should one construct this table somewhere beforehand?

Lastly, I would like to ask how to call these kind of functions from C++. (Please show me an example how to call `love.update()` from C++)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1: Does update function belongs to table love?
Yes. "function love.update(dt)" is equal to "love.update = function (dt)".

Question 2: Should one construct this table somewhere beforehand?
Yes.

Question 3: How to call these kind of functions from C++?
I assume that "love" can be accessed from global.

```
void call_love_update (lua_State* l) {
    lua_getglobal(l, "love");
    lua_getfield(l, -1, "update");
    lua_pushnumber(l, 0.016);
    lua_call(l, 1, LUA_MULTRET);
}
```

Comment: Well, a function, like other types of values, "belong" to as many variables that reference it. The field `update` in the table referenced by the expression `love` (if it does reference a table when that line is executed) will be the first variable that references the function value. Other code can copy the reference to other variables. BTW—It's possible that `love` is a variable and/or references a table created by [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/).